# Composite limit continuity of tan(x)

Tags: limits, continuity

I understand that to bring a limit "inside a function" requires it to be continuous over its given domain and evaluated limit, for example:

### $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\sin(x) = \sin(\lim_{x\to \infty}x).$$

However I'm having a slight confusion if this also applies to

### $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\tan(x) = \tan(\lim_{x\to \infty}x),$$

since it is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$ but not at $\pi/2 + n\pi$.

Comment: It doesn't make too much sense to ask if two expressions are equal to each other if the expressions are undefined in the first place (there is no such limit for $\tan$ on the LHS, and for the RHS you're asking for $\tan(\infty)$ which is undefined)

Comment: Hi sorry i should've been more specific, $x$ here should've been some other function for example $1/x$, hence the full function is $tan(1/x)$ and so i'd like to know if i can "pull in" the limit to evaluate it on $1/x$ for example to show the limit of the original function diverges/converges. Edit: should've also meant that the LHS and RHS are equivalent, not necessarily equal.